# Created a single sequence from a set of repeated sequences in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in **R** with the following format:

```
Day Agent Event ID
1   Paul  true  1
1   Mary  false 2
1   Mary  false 1
1   Paul  true  3
1   Steve true  1
2   Paul  true  1
2   Paul  false 1
2   Mary  true  1
2   Steve false 1
```

So for each day someone has an event (or not) and the event is recorded as related to other events that day by an ID.  The ID resets every day so ID 1 on day 1 has no relation to ID 1 on day 2.  I want a universal ID that spans multiple days.  So I'd like to add a column like:

```
Day Agent Event ID UniID
1   Paul  true  1  1
1   Mary  false 2  2
1   Mary  false 1  1
1   Paul  true  3  2
1   Steve true  1  1
2   Paul  true  1  3
2   Paul  false 1  3
2   Mary  true  1  3
2   Steve false 1  2
```

The purpose of the UniID is such that if I pulled all records for a given person I could line up their events in order without worrying about the day.  Any idea how to go about this?

UPDATE: Thanks for the feedback so far.  Let me clarify the day/ID/UniID again.  For every day people either do or do not experience an event (true/false).  The true/false as no influence on whether or not they get an ID.  They will always get an ID when they had the chance at the event.  So in day 1, Paul experienced an event and was given ID 1 then later that day he experienced it again and was given ID 3, Mary had two chances and did not experience it either time and received ID 1 and 2.  The IDs denote chances to experience the event inside of a given day.

The data munging comes in because the ID even counter resets every day.  So in day 2 Paul again experiences the event.  However it was also given ID 1 but it is not the same as the event in day 1.  So I want to given a sequence order that spans multiple days.

To give a different analogy think of the agents as players in baseball, the event as a chance at bat for a home run, and the day as a game.  So each player has a chance to hit a home run at every at bat and I give these at bats an ID for that game.  Now I want to take a single player and order their at bat chances from oldest to newest and give this a new ID that spans their whole career.

UPDATE 2:

Henrik's solution works quite well.  He makes a unique string factor by combining ID, Day, Agent then counts the unique factors and outputs the count as the new ID.  Thanks Henrik and good job seeing through the obfuscation of the Event.  I'll leave that stuff out next time I ask a question like this.

Comment: how are you determining the unique id?  Are you saying that the event for Paul on Day 1 is the same (non?) event for Mary on Day 1 and the same as the event for Steve on Day 1?

Comment: `UniID` makes no sense to me. Why is Mary 2 on day 1?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @SeñorO - Because she had two chances to experience an event on day 1

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - The Unique IDs are per Agent so there can be repeats.  Your example is right on, the even on day 1 for Paul is the same as the non-event on day 1 for Mary.  Whether or not they experience the event is unimportant for this ordering simply that the event chance happened on day 1 and it was both their first for that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty, but seems to work:

```
library(plyr)
dd <- read.table(text = "Day Agent Event ID
1   Paul  true  1
1   Mary  false 2
1   Mary  false 1
1   Paul  true  3
1   Steve true  1
2   Paul  true  1
2   Paul  false 1
2   Mary  true  1
2   Steve false 1", header = TRUE)

dd$ID2 <- with(dd, paste0(Day, Agent, ID))

# for each agent, create a numeric version of its ID2    
dd <- ddply(.data = dd, .variables = .(Agent), mutate, UniID = as.numeric(as.factor(ID2)))

# some clean-up
dd2 <- subset(dd, select = -ID2)
arrange(dd2, Agent, Day, UniID)
```

PS: Maybe I misunderstood something, but at least to me, the `Event` variable in your dummy data rather caused more confusion than helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah I probably should have left event out it does fuddle the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dat` is your original data.frame, try the following

```
  library(data.table)
  DT <- data.table(dat)

  DT[, uniID := seq(.N), by=list(Agent, Event)]
  DT

  #     Day Agent Event ID uniID
  #  1:   1  Paul  true  1     1
  #  2:   1  Mary false  2     1
  #  3:   1  Mary false  1     2
  #  4:   1  Paul  true  3     2
  #  5:   1 Steve  true  1     1
  #  6:   2  Paul  true  1     3
  #  7:   2  Paul false  1     1
  #  8:   2  Mary  true  1     1
  #  9:   2 Steve false  1     1
```

It's not very clear how you are determining *"uniqueness"*  But whatever criteria you are using, place that in the list in `by=` and you should be set.

Comment: The uniqueness is determined by day, agent, ID.  Thanks for the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ID has to be numeric? Does it have to be consequitive or just increasing?
Either way it seems you want an ordered sequence. So first order your data in the way you want, then add an id to each row.

```
library(data.table)

dd <- read.table(text = "Day Agent Event ID
1   Paul  true  1
1   Mary  false 2
1   Mary  false 1
1   Paul  true  3
1   Steve true  1
2   Paul  true  1
2   Paul  false 1
2   Mary  true  1
2   Steve false 1", header = TRUE)

dd <- dd[order(dd$Day,dd$Agent,dd$ID),]
dd$uniID <- seq(1:nrow(dd))

dd
  Day Agent Event ID uniID
3   1  Mary false  1     1
2   1  Mary false  2     2
1   1  Paul  true  1     3
4   1  Paul  true  3     4
5   1 Steve  true  1     5
8   2  Mary  true  1     6
6   2  Paul  true  1     7
7   2  Paul false  1     8
9   2 Steve false  1     9
```